# What does "for oneself" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The Oxford dict. interprets **reciprocate** as *"experience the same (love, liking, or affection) for someone as that person does for oneself"*. For example, *"her passion for him was not reciprocated."*

I don't quite understand "for oneself" in this interpretation. It's easy for me to fall into the illusion that *"the person (love, like) himself/herself."*

So, what does "for oneself" mean here?

Comment: [Macmillan's definition](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/reciprocate) is clearer, in my opinion: "to have the same feelings toward someone that they have for you".  This avoids the clumsy *oneself*.

Comment: @snailplane: Agreed. OP's definition is clumsy phrasing from someone who presumably didn't like the "informality" of *you*, and hence mistakenly sacrificed clarity for adherence to an outmoded concept of formal phrasing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a feeling is reciprocal:

1. Person A has that feeling for Person B.
2. Person B has that feeling for Person A.

In other words, they have the same feeling toward each other.

Let's annotate the definition so we can see which words refer to Person A and which words refer to Person B:

> **[A]** experience(s) the same (love, liking, or affection) for **someone[B]** as that **person[B]** does for **oneself[A]**

Here, *oneself* refers to the (missing) subject of the sentence, Person A.

It does not refer back to person B.